# Derby DB: how to start network server remotely

Tags: linux, ssh, derby

I want to run Derby in network mode on my virtual private server. I can connect to my server by ssh, execute

```
java -jar derbyrun.jar server start -noSecurityManager
```

and the network server starts succesfully as expected. However when I close the ssh connection that inevitably also shuts down Derby. Is there a way to start Derby without leaving the command prompt stuck, so that I can disconnect from my server and leave it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
nohup java -jar derbyrun.jar server start -noSecurityManager &
```

would work?